# What is the status of getting flash and chromium for Ubuntu ARM?

Tags: flash, arm

I have Ubuntu dual booting on a Samsung ARM Chromebook but have to go back to Chrome OS if I want to watch a flash video or do a Google Hangout. Is there a way to have these capabilities in Ubuntu for ARM now? If not, when will we have these capabilities in Ubuntu for ARM? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Folks have done it. Try sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-gnash minitube after adding the repository for it (details here http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/minitube-20-and-musique-121-released.html )

Adobe has a forum with specific details at http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1066869

Also, there are further details at

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/having-trouble-installing-flash-player-onto-chrubuntu-on-the-arm-based-chromebook-4175444859/

http://www.omappedia.org/wiki/PandaBoard_Ubuntu_PPA